# classes.jar' already contains entry 'META-INF/module_name_debug.kotlin_module', cannot overwrite

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, android-jetpack-compose

In project i am using kotlin dsl, jetpack compose, com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha08, many modules and i am continuously getting this error.

**Zip file 'E:\project_name\module_name\build\intermediates\compile_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar' already contains entry 'META-INF/module_name_debug.kotlin_module', cannot overwrite**

Any combinations of exclude/pickFirst/merge

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude/pickFirst/merge("META-INF/module_name_debug.kotlin_module")
    }
```

just doesnt work.

Is there some solution?

Comment: Do you actually have two nested `META-INF` in "Any combinations of... just doesnt work"?

Comment: thats actualy a typo, edited now

Comment: @Kochchy Have you got a chance to find any workaround?

Comment: @DimitarGenov only solution was to demodularize the app

Comment: @Kochchy I had a ticket for this issue. It gave me a good amount of grief.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183632446

There are 2 ways which resolved my issue (and I had tried anything):
1) use latest Intellij IDEA (published a week ago)
2) use Android Studio 4.2 RC1. Any other Android Studio fails mightly on my machine.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @DimitarGenov im using Jetpack Compose so i have to use Android Studio Canary

Comment: @Kochchy, were you ever able to fix this besides demodularizing the app?  I'm also having the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

reference to : [issuetracker.google.com/issues/183632446](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183632446)

disable Make Project Automatically option under:

Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler

[image]

Comment: This option is not available on Artic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4

Answer (score 2):

just delete the build ( E:\project_name\module_name\build ) folder and rebuild the project

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Bumblebee and higher. `Make project automatically(only works while not running/debugging)` option has been removed.

Upgrading your project to use the latest version of gradle in `build.gradle` and `gradle.properties` should fix this error.
For my current project I'm using this in `build.gradle`

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1"
```

`gradle.properties`

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```